# How do I get my Bitcoin private keys from app.thorswap.finance which is a native BTC cross chain swapping system?

Tags: private-key, recover-private-key

I'm testing out app.thorswap.finance for native bitcoin. Supposedly Thorchain is a cross chain swapping service with no centralized parties. Going to the app, I generated a keystore file and it comes with a Bitcoin address. I'm assuming when I send my BTC to this address, it resides under my control until I want to swap it to another coin. How do I access my Bitcoin private keys on app.thorswap.finance generated from my keystore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wallet tab > Click the folder-iconed button "View Phrase"

Go to [`https://github.com/xchainjs/xchainjs-lib/blob/master/packages/xchain-bitcoin/src/client.ts`](https://github.com/xchainjs/xchainjs-lib/blob/master/packages/xchain-bitcoin/src/client.ts). Replace `bitcoin` with your desired currency.

Search on the page with Ctrl + F for "RootDerivationPaths".

Then you'll find something like (this example is for Bitcoin):

```
    rootDerivationPaths = {
      mainnet: `84'/0'/0'/0/`,
      testnet: `84'/1'/0'/0/`,
    },
```

Drop the last `/0/`, add `m/` (e.g. `m/84'/0'/0'`).

Import the derivation path you calculated and the phrase in Electrum